# How to ui-sref a state with empty URL?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have some states defined as follows:

```
$stateProvider
        .state('home', {
                url: '/'
                , templateUrl: 'modules/trulo/client/views/browse.client.view.html'
        })

        .state('search', {
            url: '/search'
            , templateUrl: 'modules/trulo/client/views/search.client.view.html'
        })

        .state('profile', {
            url: '/profile'
            , templateUrl: 'modules/users/client/views/settings/edit-profile.client.view.html'
        })

        .state('cart', {
                url: '/cart'
                , templateUrl: 'modules/trulo/client/views/cart.html'
        })
        .state('orders', {
                url: '/orders'
                , templateUrl: 'modules/trulo/client/views/orders.html'
        })

        .state('home.myshop', {
            url: '/myshop'
            , templateUrl: 'modules/trulo/client/views/myshop.html'
        });
```

Next, I want to go back to the `home` page when I click on a button. This is done using `ui-sref` attribute on that button. 
What should be the value that should be assigned to `ui-sref` to enable me to go back to home page upon clicking that button?

I am not getting any success with any of the following :

```
<button ui-sref="">Home</button>
<button ui-sref="/">Home</button>
<button ui-sref="home">Home</button>
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use ui-sref with the name of the state which is in your case :

```
ui-sref="home"
```

Next time, don't hesitate to check docs in the internet :)
http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.directive:ui-sref

Answer (score 0):

Your state for home is declared as follow:

```js
        .state('home', {
                url: '/'
                , templateUrl: 'modules/trulo/client/views/browse.client.view.html'
        })
```

The code should be:

```
<button ui-sref="home">Home</button>
```